# Form field changes focus when I click on the text input

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a search form below that has two select input types and one text input field where the user can search by keywords. For some reason, whenever I click on keywords text box, the focus changes immediately back to the first select box drop down for Category and I so I can't type anything in the keywords text box. Can anyone see why this is happening?

```
$categories_list = array();
$ratings_list = array();

try {
$query = $dbh->query("SELECT category, genre, rating FROM posts WHERE 1
GROUP BY category, genre, rating");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$iterator = new IteratorIterator($query);
foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    if (empty($row['category']) == false && !in_array($row['category'],
$categories_list))
        $categories_list[] = $row['category'];
    if (empty($row['rating']) == false && !in_array($row['rating'],
$ratings_list))
        $ratings_list[] = $row['rating'];
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
}
?>


<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2>Search Completed Stories</h2>
<form name="search" method="get" 
action="http://example.com/searchB/">
<label>
    Category:
    <select name="category">
        <?php foreach($categories_list as $category) : ?>
            <option><?php echo $category; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</label>
<label>
    Rating:
    <select name="rating">
            <option value="">Any</option>
        <?php foreach($ratings_list as $rating) : ?>
            <option><?php echo $rating; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</label>
<label>
    Keywords:
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="active" value="0">
<input type="submit"/>
```

Comment: Changing focus is useally caused by some type of Javascript, yet I don't see any JS in your code. As far as I know, PHP cannot reset the focus after the page is already loaded.

Comment: I guess that might be it. You are right that I am not using any JS anywhere on the page.

Comment: Oddly it works fine on a development page. But when I place this code on to another page that has another list of results, then I get this focus issue with the keywords input text box

Comment: Well there's nothing in your code above that will cause a change of focus. So something else must be going on. You can try providing additional code or, if there's no other option, provide a link where this script is running. I might be able to see more if I actually see it happening.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but it appears to be the wordpress template causing the issue. I used the exact same code on another wordpress template and it works fine.

Comment: It appears that I solved the problem but simply changing the <label> tags to <p> tags instead. I guess that got around the conflict.

Comment: Hmm although that's a bit odd, I'm glad you've got it figured out.

Comment: This question does not show enough code to be answerable. It is probably, some kind of JS. Your answer did not solve whatever the problem you didn't state was.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I solved the problem by simply changing the label
tags to p tags instead. I guess that got around the conflict.